# Eigenvectors of a Matrix Homework

Tags: matrices

Find eigenvectors of:
\begin{pmatrix}4 & 2 \\ 2 & 3 \end{pmatrix}
$$\det(A-\lambda I) = \lambda^2-7 \lambda+8=0 \iff \lambda_1=\frac{7+\sqrt{17}}{2} \ \lor \ \lambda_2= \frac{7-\sqrt{17}}{2}$$

$$\lambda_1\iff4x+2y= \frac{7+\sqrt{17}}{2}x $$
$$\lambda_1\iff2x+3y= \frac{7+\sqrt{17}}{2}y $$
$$\lambda_2\iff4x+2y= \frac{7-\sqrt{17}}{2}x $$
$$\lambda_2\iff2x+3y= \frac{7-\sqrt{17}}{2}y $$
When my lecturer did an example in class the linear equations he got from the eigenvalue told him the eigenvectors but I did'nt really understand how he did it... Please can someone help, ideally using this method. By solving the simultaneous equations I got:

$$\lambda_1\iff\begin{pmatrix}1  \\ \frac{-1+\sqrt{17}}{4}  \end{pmatrix} $$
$$\lambda_2\iff\begin{pmatrix}1  \\ \frac{-1-\sqrt{17}}{4}  \end{pmatrix} $$
The question says to normalise the eigenvectors how would I do that?

Comment: Move erverything to the left. These are two linear systems that you have to solve for $x,y$.

Comment: So I solve for x and y in both sets of simultaneous equations, put that in a column vector and thats my "eigenvector" right?

Comment: Yes, for each system, you'll find a one dimensional subspace of solutions. These are the two eigenspaces of this matrix.

Comment: Is the above correct?

Comment: Lecturers are usually careful to give only examples in which the numbers work out more nicely than this....

Answer (score 1):

When you set up your system of equations for $\lambda = \frac{7}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{17}}{2}$ ,
you'll have

$$(\frac{1 + \sqrt{17}}{2} ) x \ + \ 2y \ = \ 0 $$

$$ 2x \ + \ (\frac{-1 + \sqrt{17}}{2})y \ = \ 0 \ .$$

This is sufficient horrid-looking that one might just want to use $(1 \ \ -\frac{1 + \sqrt{17}}{4} )^T$ and let it go at that, as the obvious solution to $ \ \alpha x = -2y$ .  It will turn out that this impulse is actually correct, since the second equation produces

$$2  \cdot 1 \ + \ (\frac{-1 + \sqrt{17}}{2})  \cdot (\frac{-1 - \sqrt{17}}{4})  \ = \ 2 \ +  (\frac{1}{8} - \frac{17}{8}) \ = \ 0 \ .$$

For the "conjugate" eigenvalue, $\lambda = \frac{7}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{17}}{2}$ , the sign on the irrational part of the second entry in the eigenvector will "flip".  (A similar behavior appears when we work with *complex* conjugate eigenvalues.)

Normalizing these eigenvectors requires you to find their "lengths" in order to divide their components through to make them into unit vectors.  We have a length-squared of

$$s_1^2 \ = \ (1)^2 \ + \ [(-\frac{1}{4})^2 \ +  \ 2 \cdot (-\frac{1}{4}) \cdot (-\frac{\sqrt{17}}{4}) + (-\frac{\sqrt{17}}{4})^2] \ = \ \frac{17 + \sqrt{17}}{8} \ $$

and similarly for $s_2^2$ (note that $s_1 \neq s_2$).

You would have

$$(\frac{1}{s_1} \ \ \frac{\frac{-1 - \sqrt{17}}{4}}{s_1} )^T \ \ \text{and} \ \ (\frac{1}{s_2} \ \ \frac{\frac{-1 + \sqrt{17}}{4}}{s_2} )^T  \, $$

whatever those work out to be exactly. (I don't think the division is going to be pretty...)